# What layer of my application should my Guava caches be in?

Tags: java, caching

I have a working Struts application right now and currently, in the server side, there are three layers: controller, service, and dao/database layer.

I currently have Guava caches on my service layer but I feel that it's in the wrong place seeing that in some of my `CacheLoader`'s I use my services to retrieve data. So what's happening now is that my "service has cache" while my "cache has service". Seems wrong...

What should be done here?

Comment: It depends on who manages the data. If the DAL is shared by services then they manage the lifecycle and therefore caches. If the services own all data access then it manages caching (the DAL is just ORM boilerplate). I prefer the latter, but both are common.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question deserves a long(er) answer. Let's consider a web application.

It may be useful to put in caches at or inside any layer of the application. There are advantages and disadvantages.

#### DAO / database

Caching may introduce consistency issues. If an object gets updated, it needs to be invalidated in the cache. It is a good idea to concentrate this logic inside the DAO.

Furthermore, the DAO layer interface should make it easy to insert a cache: There are objects that are retrieved by a key.

#### Service

If the service does a complex calculation on top of the data provided by the DAO and this is accessed very often it may be desirable to cache the computation result.

If the service does provide data from external servers, it is also a good idea to cache it.

#### Controller

Conceptually this can be more or different things. So I back off from using the word.

#### Web Tier / Templates

Caching can be useful for (partial) render results.

For example if you have a multi lingual web application, but only one mainly requested language it is more useful to cache the render results rather then the intermediate service results.

#### Web Tier / Request Level

Cache the whole contents of a web request.

#### Some Discussion

You can cache on different layers, but it may lead to a lot of headache. If you cache on the service layer and within the web tier, then the caches are stacked. If you configure each cache with an expiry of 5 minutes, this means that in the worst case a value can be stuck for 10 minutes. This is undesirable.

OTOH, let's say you have a business requirement that says: "I want to have the top 10 list of my product sales recalculated every 5 minutes". That is a perfect use case for a cache with defined expiry inside the service. But, you may need to propagate the expiry time through the stack, if there are caches "above".

Let's consider an application that caches rendered HTML pages or parts and supports 5 different languages. The cache may store a lot of redundant content, but the access time is faster as when the application uses cached objects from the DAO and renders the content again and again. So in general, caching more "down the stack" is more memory efficient and caching more "up the stack" will improve latency, reduce CPU usage but may need more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Files, databases, external servers that provides/preserves data... they're considered data sources, and should be accessed through Data Access Layer (commonly known as DAO).

Since cache is another place where you will store/retrieve data that resides in memory, then it's better to handle the data access through an interface that belongs to Data Access Layer.

Comment: So should I remove my caches and move it to another class? Because right now my caches are static variables inside my service

Comment: You should do the proper refactor. How to do it belongs to another question.